# Firefox Addon-SDK Panel Scroll Bars

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, panel, firefox-addon-sdk

How do I get rid of unwanted vertical and horizontal scrollbars that appear from the panel module in the sdk? My options are as follows:

```
var panel = require("sdk/panel").Panel({
  width: 370,
  height: 150,
  position:{
    top: -5,
    right: 8
  },
  contentURL: data.url("panel.html"),
  contentScriptWhen: "ready",
  contentScriptFile: [data.url("js/jquery.js"), 
                      data.url("js/panel.js")]
});
```

EDIT: I was able to solve this problem by adding a CSS Property to Body (overflow: hidden) as graciously recommended by either ZER0 or _zombie on #jetpack, I forget which!

Comment: Can you add the code for 'panel.html'? This code can also affect the visibility of the scrollbars

Comment: Problem solved :), I take caution when posting source code publicly. I   had to learn in a pretty embarrassing way, so I limit doing so. Either way, its fixed with the CSS property. Thanks for taking interest.

Comment: well, feel free to up-vote my comment then :)

Answer (score 1):

Add `overflow: hidden;` to the `style` of the `<body>`.

Answer was provided by BAMbanda itself in in the question, copying it here to preserve SO's structure.